# Correct Typo's in TEXT INPUT -> String

Tags: java, algorithm, data-cleaning

I'm doing an exercices of data-cleaning and i have some typo's in the days input.

```
You sold 356 items across all Mondy of the year 
You sold 1687 items across all Thrrsday of the year 
You sold 1718 items across all Tuesdly of the year
```

This is what i get ...
The question is, how can i manage to get the day right ?
I was thinking about making something like :

```
String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
```

and then compare my LINE to each day and see if there is atleast 80% of the chars of the line in a day ...

Can someone help me ?

I expect to correct the input (NO LIB ALLOWED)

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow ! Unfortunately, we're not a free do-my-homework service. You should show us what you tried and what specific problem you encounter. I suggest you to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: up please, do someone have an idea ...